why apache doesn't shutdown on Mac?
i get this error when i try to stop apache web server on Mac M2:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'j#', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
i try sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp restartapache
AMPP: Stopping Apache...fail.
apachectl returned 1.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
i try to stop him from panel menu , and i get the same description.

So what does the file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf contain?  It looks like there is a spurious character before the comment.
